# Preventing server tracking of Greasemonkey, cross-domain form submits

Tags: submit, http-post, greasemonkey, tracking, form-submit

I have a Greasemonkey script that dynamically inserts an HTML form into some web pages. The form can then be POSTed, by the user, for processing to a PHP script on a different domain.

The GM script inserts something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://somedomain.com/process.php">
<input type="text name="sometext">
<input type="submit" name="s" value="submit!">
</form>
```

Now, is there any way for the web site to know where this form gets submitted to? Is it possible to prevent this (using browser or other settings), and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but you are putting something in the DOM of the site (client-side) with greasemonkey, right?

Well, normally they would not notice this, and you are posting (still from the client side) to another place, so you'd be in the clear.

But if the site is REALLY PARANOID, tinfoil hat style, I suppose they could be fireing events that when they fire AFTER you've modified the dom and do stuff. But that would be kinda rediculous to presume. still, it could do something like

- catch all submits from any form (including yours)
- find all forms on the site and read their 'action'
- find all code in the site that was not there origionally.

But that code should be visible for you from the source. Could be obfuscated and all, but still, it would run client-side, so you should be able to control it. I'd really not worry about that.

Comment: Thank you for our answer. Yes, I am basically injecting a long string of HTML form code into the source of the page. I am not concerned either with that kind of paranoia. Just thought if they're using something like Google Analytics (some of them are), it may tell them where my form gets submitted to, unless the user blocks GA with some selective script blocker. (which in turn may be a solution to the whole problem, but a somewhat tedious one)

Comment: I don't see how that would work, apart from a script that catches your clicks, but the event-handlers of your form are not there when that script is most likely to execute. So your script is fine as you're doing a complete client-side thing. Only if they keep on adding event-listeners to make sure no additional form was added (which would be too much paranoia indeed) they could theoretically find something as far as I can think of, so in other words you're probably in the clear :)

Answer (score 1):

The Web Site could potentially use JavaScript to capture the HTML you have added, including the action URL and any data in the form. It is highly unlikely that the sites owners would do this, but it is a possibility.

One solution is to disable JavaScript for that WebSite, Greasemonkey will still run even if JavaScript is in your browser.

Comment: +1.  Disabling a site's JS is the ultimate anti, anti-Greasemonkey defense. (GM can replace paranoid, page JS if necessary.)